# Change Wordpress %postname% Permalink Separator

Tags: wordpress

I wish to change the Wordpress %postname% Permalink Separator from dashes to underscores or any other such separator.

Eg.

Change: http://www.myblog.com/my-first-post/

to

http://www.myblog.com/my_first_post/

I am certain it might be possible to do but I do not know how. Can someone kindly guide me or point me towards the right direction?

If I use a mod_rewrite, what would the lines in my .htaccess be for me to achieve the above?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. In order to change your url 

   From:http://www.myblog.com/my-first-post/

   To:http://www.myblog.com/my_first_post/

2. You need to go to Admin dashboard->Pages.In right side it will list out all pages of 
   website.There move the mouse to the page name(myfirstpost),below you will see edit 
   link and click on edit.

3. Edit page will open,in that below the page title,near permalink,click on edit and 
   change '-'(my-first-post) to '_'(my_first_post) and click ok.

4. Then,don't forget to click Update button on right side of the same page.Then view 
   the website for the change.
```